# How do I code a login page in C# while verifying login details in SQL Database?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Ok, I am at wits end.  I have a login page for teachers.  The Username which is the teacher ID(integer) and the password(string) have to match what's already in the Teachers table that I've got in SQL. Please be aware that my knowledge and understanding is very basic. This is part of an assignment for C# module in SD Diploma. Obviously my code so far is not working.  What an I doing wrong?  My code is below....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace School_System_Project
{
public partial class Login2 : Form
{

SqlConnection conn;
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataTable table = new DataTable();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();

public Login2()
{
InitializeComponent();
}


private void btnTLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string msg = "Teacher ID or Password cannot be left blank!";

if (txtTID.Text == "")
{
lblMessage1.Text = msg;
return;
}

if (txtTPW.Text == "")
{
lblMessage1.Text = msg;
return;
}


conn = new SqlConnection
(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Name of connection string"].ConnectionString);        
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Connection = conn;
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.CommandText = "SELECT TID, Password FROM Teacher WHERE TID = @ID 
AND Password = @Password";
command.Connection.Open();

SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@ID";
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
param.Value = txtTID.Text;
command.Parameters.Add(param).Value = Int32.Parse(txtTID.Text);

SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
param2.ParameterName = "@Password";
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
param.Value = txtTPW.Text;
command.Parameters.Add(param2);





adapter.SelectCommand = command;
adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();




if (txtTID.Text == param.ParameterName && txtTPW.Text == param2.ParameterName)                                               
{
MainTeachers mainteachers = new MainTeachers();
mainteachers.ShowDialog();
}


else
{
lblMessage1.Text = "Incorrect login details, please try again";
}

reader.Dispose();
command.Dispose();
conn.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: " Obviously my code so far is not working." - must try harder.

Comment: Is that the best you got Mitch?  Pathetic

Comment: SO is not here to debug for you. If you have an error describe it (obviously).

Comment: Sorry about that Mitch.  This is my 2nd question ever.  Ok, where it says "adapter.SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();" a FormatException pops up saying "Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32."  what does that mean?  I am really confused and I don't have much to go by at present.  Does my code look like the way it should look for this type of thing?

Comment: Seems a copy - paste problem, take a deeper look at your param2...

Comment: There are tons of things that is wrong with your code Ben. SO members are really helpful if they see the poster as someone who is doing majority of the work and asking here for additional input. Your code shows that you really have not studied about the work you are faced with. We cannot answer something so broad.

Comment: Not studied?  I've bee at home, online everyday, for the past 18 months, not working, trying to make sense of this. I batle constant lag, connection drop outs and instructors that barely know the course material.  The activities we do are nothing compared to our assignments.  It's just not taught very well I'm afraid.

Comment: I find that hard to believe ben because a quick 15 minute google on the objects sqlparameter and sqldatareader would have improved this code dramatically.

Answer (score 2):

OK - lots of stuff to clear up...

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@ID";
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
param.Value = txtTID.Text;
command.Parameters.Add(param).Value = Int32.Parse(txtTID.Text);
```

Why are you setting the value twice? First you set it to what looks like a string (but the parameter is defined as `SqlDbType.Int`, and then you add the parameter and set its value *again* - this time to an int. Which one of those assignments do you want to keep??

```
SqlParameter param2 = new SqlParameter();
param2.ParameterName = "@Password";
param.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
```

From here on out, you're using `param.`, while the parameter you're defining is really `param2` - copy&paste error??? Needs to be fixed!

Also: is the password parameter **really** of type `SqlDbType.Int`??? .....

Please tell me you're ***not really*** storing all those passwords **in clear text** in your database! That would be a ***MAJOR*** no-no and gaping security issue in your system!

Also: you execute your reader - but you're never really **reading** any data from it.....

I would rewrite your code to something like this to take advantage of all the usual best practices working with ADO.NET and raw SQL:

```
// define the query you want to execute
string query = "SELECT TID, Password FROM Teacher WHERE TID = @ID AND Password = @Password";

// establish connection and command objects, both wrapped into using(){} blocks to 
// ensure proper disposal, even in case of an exception
using (conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Name of connection string"].ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
   // add paramters and set values
   command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtTID.Text);
   command.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtTPW.Text;

   // open connection
   conn.Open();

   // execute your reader
   using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
   {
       // you need to actually *read* from the reader here! What are you trying to do?
       // just check if that row with ID and password exist? Fetch some data?
       bool idExists = reader.HasRows();
       reader.Close();
   }

   conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Hey mate, thanks a lot for your help hey.  Have been struggling with this for a while.  I didn't realize I had they data types wrong.  I gave the ID the parameter name of "param" and "param2" was for the password.  Are you saying they should be the same?  I'm confused.  The Database was created by our instructors.  We're just learning how to do basic coding, not focusing at all on security.  It's supposed to be visible for our convenience of learning.  This coding makes me nervous hey, I've had a few panic attacks because of this stuff lol

Comment: Where am I defining the ID as a string?  "@ID" is just the name of the parameter.  It's an integer in a textbox.  Do I need the Int32.Parse?  Not sure where I got that...

Comment: he means this code param.Value = txtTID.Text;. With that you have set @ID to what ever string is inside txtTID

Answer (score 0):

Except for the error pointed out by Rahul Singh.

The data that you want is inside your SqlDataReader reader variable. param.ParameterName will always be "@ID"

Try logging in with the user = @ID and password= @Password and you will be redirected to the form.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean sorry but thanks anyway

Comment: You do not understand because clearly you used objects that you didnt study on. Read more what this objects do rather than relying on spoonfed answers from SO. Harsh i know because i was in your position as well but trust me. Spoonfed answers are not what you want in the long run.

Comment: No I don't want spoonfed.  The problem is that there's just too many answers to any given problem.  I've already learned a few new things anyway.  I'll leave it there.  It'll just get even more confusing to me